# How to add initial value to redux form radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added redux form to my reactjs app where I have with text and radio button. I want to add initial values to all the field which comes from backend api. But the problem is the way i tried i am getting initial value for text but not for radio button.

This is how I did for text see my code below.

> editProfile.jsx

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Grid>
                            <Field name="name" component={renderInputField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Field
                                name="dob"
                                showTime={false}
                                component={renderDateTimePicker}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid>

                            <Field  style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} name="sex" component={renderRadioButton}>
                                <RadioButton value="male" label="male"/>Male
                                <RadioButton value="female" label="female"/>Female
                            </Field>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Field name="contact" normalize={normalizePhone} component={renderInputField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            {/*<Field name="address" component={renderInputField} />*/}
                            <Link to={"/add-new-address"}>{'>'}</Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <div style={{paddingTop: '20px'}}>
                            <LoadingButton type={"submit"} title={'Save'}/>
                        </div>
                    </form>


EditProfileForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'EditProfileForm',
    enableReinitialize: true,
    validate,
})(EditProfileForm);

EditProfileForm = connect(
    state => ({
        initialValues: {
            name: state.editProfileData.profileData.username,
            profilePic: state.editProfileData.profileData.profilePic,
            dob: state.editProfileData.profileData.dateOfBirth,
            sex: state.editProfileData.profileData.gender,
            contact: state.editProfileData.profileData.phoneNumber,
        }

    })
)(EditProfileForm)

export default EditProfileForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your value is in valueProp you can compare that to the value of the corresponding radioButton and check the one where it matches.
(you didn't show how you handle the values inside your form and I'm not familiar with that Form package you use)

```
<RadioButton value="male" label="male" checked={valueProp === 'male'} />Male
<RadioButton value="female" label="female" checked={valueProp === 'female'} />Female
```

Basically you need to turn your RadioButton into a controlled component because the universal Field component will only try to set the value prop of the component it renders (i.e. an input tag), but that's not how RadioButtons work.

RadioButtons work differently from other input tags in that they don't change their state based on the value prop/attribute. Instead the value of each RadioButton is predefined and doesn't change when you interact with it like it would do for a textbox for example.
You also can't control the checked state of a RadioButton from its surrounding element.
Instead to select one of multiple RadioButtons with the same name, you need to set the checked prop of each RadioButton if the corresponding form value matches the value of the RadioButton.

Comment: Sorry, had a typo in my code. But I also added some more explanations in case you're misunderstanding my code as a readymade solution. I don't know enough about the environment to give a working code. You can't automatically handle RadioButtons with the Field component, but need to make them into a controlled component by hand.